# iOS GoogleSignIn Crash or compiling error

Tags: google-signin

```
Device: iPhone 6
OS version: 11.4.1
SDK version: 4.4.0 and 3.0.0
Xcode version: 10.1
```

When I use the latest version of 4.4.0, I get an error when compiling, I have added the required dependencies, but I still report this error

the error is as follows:

> Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>   "_kGTMSessionFetcherStatusDomain", referenced from:
>   -[GIDGTMOAuth2SignIn authCodeObtained] in GoogleSignIn(GIDGTMOAuth2SignIn_71ef1dfd0402a1e93e15806c6a0abcff.o)
>   "_GTMSessionFetcherAssertValidSelector", referenced from:
>   -[GIDGTMOAuth2Authentication authorizeRequest:delegate:didFinishSelector:] in
>   GoogleSignIn(GIDGTMOAuth2Authentication_5da5b4c347b221d22d73c3f25a1d0af9.o)
>   -[GIDGTMOAuth2SignIn initWithAuthentication:authorizationURL:delegate:webRequestSelector:finishedSelector:]
>   in GoogleSignIn(GIDGTMOAuth2SignIn_71ef1dfd0402a1e93e15806c6a0abcff.o)
>   "OBJC_CLASS$_GTMSessionFetcherService", referenced from:
>   objc-class-ref in
>   GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn_2f842adf59cff94dba6bfcb1043c2758.o)
>   "OBJC_CLASS$_GTMSessionFetcher", referenced from: objc-class-ref in
>   GoogleSignIn(GIDRuntimeConfigFetcher_d7b0ff2f28d2ece58e787c51382387f7.o)
>   objc-class-ref in
>   GoogleSignIn(GIDSignIn_2f842adf59cff94dba6bfcb1043c2758.o)
>   objc-class-ref in
>   GoogleSignIn(GIDGTMOAuth2Authentication_5da5b4c347b221d22d73c3f25a1d0af9.o)
>   objc-class-ref in
>   GoogleSignIn(GIDGTMOAuth2SignIn_71ef1dfd0402a1e93e15806c6a0abcff.o)
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Excluded everything about arm64, but still compiled error。

I downloaded the 3.0.0 version of the SDK, just replace it and compile successfully. I thought that this problem was solved, but another problem appeared.

GIDSignInButton button click to crash。the error is as follows:

> invalid mode 'kCFRunLoopCommonModes' provided to CFRunLoopRunSpecific
>   - break on _CFRunLoopError_RunCalledWithInvalidMode to debug. This message will only appear once per execution.

It has been two days, and I have tried it for countless times and still can't run normally. Someone encountered a similar situation, request to share the solution！！！